# cloneConnectFn is not a function when using $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm working on a project that's using typescript and angular to generate dynamic web content. Currently, my job is to format an input field as currency, which is simple enough in plain javascript (with angular), but I need to do it in typescript, which is presenting some problems. Here's my directive (which I formatted as a class as per another stack overflow answer suggested)

```
namespace incode.directives.label {
    interface IScope extends ng.IScope {
        amount: number;
    }
    export class IncodeCurrencyInputDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict ='A';
        public require: 'ngModel';
        public scope: Object;
        replace = true;
        public link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn | ng.IDirectivePrePost;


        constructor(private $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
            this.scope = {
                amount: '='
            };
            this.link = (scope: IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, ctlr: any, $filter: ng.IFilterService) => {
                //element.bind('focus',
                //    function () {
                //        element.val(scope.amount);
                //    });
                element.bind('input',
                    function () {
                        scope.amount = element.val();
                        scope.$apply;
                    });
                element.bind('blur',
                    function () {
                        element.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));
                    });

            }
        }




        public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            var directive = ($filter) => new IncodeCurrencyInputDirective($filter);
            directive.$inject = ['$filter'];
            return directive;
        }


    }

    angular.module('incode.module')
        .directive('ixCurrency', incode.directives.label.IncodeCurrencyInputDirective.factory());
}
```

and here's the template that uses it

```
<md-input-container layout-fill class="number-range">
        <input placeholder="From"
               type="text"
               name="from"
               ix-currency
               amount="0.00"
               precision="{{rangeController.precision}}"
               ng-model="rangeController.Bucket.RangeFilterFromString"/>
</md-input-container>
```

As it stands at the moment, the script generates an error on blur: `TypeError: cloneConnectFn is not a function` which seems like a very low-level function used by angular, and shouldn't normally be producing this error. Any insight you can provide is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Since I know a lot of angular gurus have never touched typescript, I'll attach a pastebin of the compiled javascript, in case that helps http://pastebin.com/NnTLqauL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, no idea why it was giving me that error precisely, but the root of the problem is a miscommunication of scope between typescript and angular. You'll notice I have the line

`element.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));`

in the `'blur'` binding above. The reason I reference filter in this way is because if you write `this.$filter`, typescript compiles it such that even though it's inside an object, `this` refers to `window` instead of the object, so `$filter` is out of scope. The solution is to use a lambda function to spoof the scoping like so:

```
element.bind('blur',
    () => {
        element.val(this.$filter('currency')(scope.amount));
    });
```

Always be mindful of where `this` points (something extremely difficult for me it seems) and you should be fine.